# „Powered by Google“ image is missing

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api, google-places

I'm using the GMSAutocompleteViewController and just set the autocompleteBounds and autocompleteFilter properties. Since it is no custom component, it should display the "Powered by Google" image automatically, but it doesn't. I used an iPhone 5S with iOS 10.3.3 and 6S Plus with iOS 11.0.3 for testing.

Here is the code:

```
private func showGooglePlaces() {

    let autocompleteViewController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
    autocompleteViewController.delegate = self

    if let currentLocation = currentLocation {
        let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: currentLocation.coordinate, coordinate: currentLocation.coordinate)
        autocompleteViewController.autocompleteBounds = bounds

    } else {
        let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
        filter.type = .establishment
        filter.country = "DE"
        autocompleteViewController.autocompleteFilter = filter
    }

    present(autocompleteViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

[image]